# How to properly configure ingress cache to get it working?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I'm trying to configure cache for a specific host, but getting 404. Also It seems my config was not included into final nginx.conf. This file doesn't contain it

My ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: images-ingress
  labels:
    last_updated: "14940999355"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_cache static-cache;
      proxy_cache_valid 404 10m;
      proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_404 http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_x_purge;
      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - static.qwstrs.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod
  rules:
  - host: static.qwstrs.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: imaginary
          servicePort: 9000
```

If I remove this sample

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_cache static-cache;
      proxy_cache_valid 404 10m;
      proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_404 http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_x_purge;
      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
```

everything works but without cache

even if I have one line from snippet above It produces 404 error and doesn't work

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_cache static-cache;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To enable caching, you need to configure the [proxy_cache_path](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/#enabling-the-caching-of-responses) for the `nginx-ingress-controller`.
You can do it by modifying the `ConfigMap` for `nginx-ingress-controller`.

---

I've created an example to illustrate you how it works (I assume you have [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)).

First, create a `ConfigMap` named `ingress-nginx-controller` as described in the documentation [custom_configuration](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-configuration/#custom-configuration):
**Note:** You may need to modify the `proxy_cache_path` settings, but shared memory zone (keys_zone=**static-cache**) should be the same as in your `proxy_cache` directive.

```
$ cat configmap.yml
# configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: default
data:
  http-snippet: "proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=static-cache:10m max_size=10g  inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;"
  
$ kubectl apply -f configmap.yml 
configmap/ingress-nginx-controller configured
```

And then create the `Ingress` resource ( I've modified your ingress resource a bit to demonstrate how `X-Cache-Status` header works):

```
$ cat ingress.yml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: images-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_cache static-cache;
      proxy_cache_valid any 60m;
      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - static.qwstrs.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod
  rules:
  - host: static.qwstrs.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: imaginary
          servicePort: 9000
          
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yml
ingress.extensions/images-ingress configured
```

Finally we can check:

```
$ curl -k -I https://static.qwstrs.com
HTTP/2 200
...
x-cache-status: MISS
accept-ranges: bytes

$ curl -k -I https://static.qwstrs.com
HTTP/2 200
...
x-cache-status: HIT
accept-ranges: bytes
```

More information on `proxy_cache_path` and `proxy_cache` can be found [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/#How-to-Set-Up-and-Configure-Basic-Caching).

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you